# Go dependent functions / nested functions best practices with context

Tags: go, goroutine

Suppose I have a go program that executes a long running job (generally as a goroutine), where there are many steps and each step is dependent on the completion of the last, i.e.

`A -> B -> C -> D`

So generally, the way I would go around doing this is for `A()` to call `B()` at the end of its function, and so on. A switch statement? But how would we determine the order of operations?

Thank you.

Is this good practice, i.e. nesting functions? Is there a cleaner way to do this such that it's easier to read in code? I'm not too sure if there is another way to do it.

What if I wanted to pass a `context.CancelFunc` throughout the 'chain' so that I can cancel the process between A and B, or B and C, etc?

Comment: *many steps where each depends on the previous*, isnt that procedural? You can call B after A and not from within A.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to implement the Pipeline pattern where all your stages are connected through channels, as described in this detailed article
https://go.dev/blog/pipelines

> Each stage has any number of inbound and outbound channels, except the
> first and last stages, which have only outbound or inbound channels,
> respectively. The first stage is sometimes called the source or
> producer; the last stage, the sink or consumer.